# Angular RegEx matching injections

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to write a regex matching every dependency for a angular 1.5 class. This is what I got so far:

```
\$inject = \[('([\w]+)'([,]?[\s]?))*
```

This is what is a couple of test lines:

```
MyController.$inject = ['service1', 'service2', 'service3'];

MyController
    .$inject = [
        'service1',
        'service2',
        'service3',
    ];
```

This should be the result:

```
match = ['service1', 'service2', 'service3'];
```

But my regex above will only fetch the last item: `service3`, and I don't know why. Can anybody help?

**Update**

Got it working here: http://regexr.com/3e6c2

Comment: Consider using [Esprima](http://esprima.org) to make matching easier and far more accurate than a regex.

Comment: I did not know about this parser. Thanks, but I want this to be lightweight. Throwing every file I pick up through this parser, will exchange the trouble of interpret the actual code file for having to interpret a resultset from this parser. I'm not sure this will bring value to what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that when you quantify a capture group, only the last one is captured. You allow 0-unlimited repetitions of the capture group with the `*`. You'll have to capture them individually for it to work.

For an illustration, [see this example at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/iP3nA1/2). Here I've repeated the capture group three times instead of having a quantifier, and thus all three groups get capture.

I've also made some of the groups *non-capturing* (`(?:...`) to avoid *noise* in the groups.

This works if there's an finite number of groups. If the number of groups is unknown/to large you'll have to solve it programmatically.

Comment: So for an unknown capture group I have to do this in two steps? There is no way of capturing the comma separated list between [ and ]; in one step?

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to do this instead then: `\$inject = \[([a-zA-Z0-9_,'\s]+)\]`, thus capturing everything, and trim the result using javascript replace or something...

Comment: Not to my knowledge. But I'm a bit confused - do you already have the result in an array? Or is it a string you're parsing?

Comment: I'm parsing an entire javascript code file. Trying to retreive what injections the file has. This is for a node script I'm writing.

Comment: Ok. I think you should do it in two steps then - first find the data between the `[]` (e.g. `/\[([^]]*)\]/`) and then `String.match` the separate items in quotes `/'[^']*'/g` and you'll have them in an array.